# Checking if Spinner is empty SQLite

Tags: android

I'm creating SQLite app which has a Spinner. The Spinner contains values from database table (query which takes one column).
If database is empty - the spinner obviously remains empty too.
I need a condition that tells me if Spinner is empty or not to make some validation.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> categories;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner spinner;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
categories = databaseHelper.getAllCategories();

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And my on-click method condition:

```
...
else if(<the condition i need>) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No category selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
...
```

Comment: check the count of items

Comment: That worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

check the size of array :

```
 if (categories == null || categories.size() == 0) {
 //display your Toast
 }
```

Or you can use getCount() method :

```
 if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
 //display your Toast
 }
```

Comment: ok, as you want :) please consider marking solution as best so as to help future user having similar issue :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getSelectedItem()`. It will return currently selected item.

```
If (spinner.getSelectedItem() == null)
{
    //To do if nothing selected.
}
```

Comment: What does having no selected item have to do with the spinner being empty? This answer is wrong.